# How to instance a named Excel.Application object to allow for post-macro garbage collection after the unexpected

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm a relative VBA novice, and designing a fairly complex macro that can run for anything between 10 seconds and 10 minutes, which does most of its work in another invisible instance of Excel created by `Dim appDatabaseInstance = New Excel.Application` . There are a number of functions and subroutines that get used over the course of code execution, and whilst I've done my best to ensure that `appDatabaseInstance.Quit` is called whenever anything semi-predictable goes wrong, there's one thing I can't control - the user.

Specifically, if a user decides the program has crashed and holds escape, VBA will break execution, and because of how the break took place, none of my garbage collection routines (I think) end up taking place.

As such, I'd be much happier if I could somehow name the instance I create in a predictable manner, and then attempt, before creating a new instance, to find an existing one and deal with it appropriately. That way even if an unfortunate application instance gets left open, it will get closed as soon as the user tries anything else involving the programme (and if they don't, then one instance is unlikely to cause too many headaches in the context).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you display a progress bar to the user? If not this would help their patience?

Comment: Not for the time being, but I'm actually not even 100% certain how I'd reliably measure progress, since it's not until the bulk of the operation is completed that I know how many operations I'll need to perform. That said, as I say, complete novice.

Comment: That certainly makes it harder to report if the scope cant be predicted ..... I have used a variant of [Walkenbach's progress bar](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/) on both my addins (see my profile), on the Duplicate Master I used the `xlDisable` option for `EnableCancelKey` but then periodically check if the user had clicked `Cancel` on my userform to got to a controlled exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `EnableCancelKey` property of the Application object to determine what will happen when a user interrupts your code

I suggest you see [this post on EnableCancelKey](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/05/22/enablecancelkey) at Dick's Blog.

As a summary, `EnableCancelKey` has three possible settings:

- **xlDisable** – Prevents the user from interrupting the code
- **xlInterrupt** – Normal operation. The debugger is shown and the code is in debug mode at whichever line it happened to be when it was  interrupted.
- **xlErrorHandler** – Raises error number 18 and reacts just like any other error. If you have error handling set up, it’s called.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion! Even I use EnableCancelKey with xlErrorHandler in such scenarios. It is safe and reliable, provided appropriate error handling is done in the code else the code can crash if it enters an infinite loop.

Comment: This sounds like the key I'm looking for. As near as I can tell, other errors should go through my error handlers; it's just the interrupt one.

Answer (score 3):

I've had to do something similar in VBA before. The follow method will close all other excel process except the one that is currently running the code. **Please remember to save your stuff before attempting to run this code!**

```
Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub CloseOtherInstances()

  Dim currentId As Long
  Dim wmiObj As Object
  Dim process As Object
  Dim processes As Object

  currentId = GetCurrentProcessId

  Set wmiObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

  Set processes = wmiObj.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name ='EXCEL.exe'")

  For Each process In processes
    If process.ProcessId <> currentId Then process.Terminate
  Next process

End Sub
```

Comment: The WMI is very useful if you want to close other instances but in this case prevention of user error is better than cure :)

Comment: @brettdj I agree with you. I gave him what he asked for, you gave him what he needed. At least this code will be here for any other explicitly looking for closing excel.

Comment: Hmm... sounds like it might be worth implementing. I wonder if I should try and run it when the application housing the workbook closes, with an appropriate promp to the user of course...?

Comment: You could do that. That would help to ensure the hidden instance doesn't linger.